# MySQL Auto increment not incrementing

Tags: mysql, sql

I've created a table with 3 columns: postID, userID, and comment.

I have the postID as the primary key, and I am trying to make this auto-increment every time I add a new row to the table.

```
INSERT INTO CommentTable (postID, userID, comment) VALUES (DEFAULT, "test", "test")
```

When I run this query, it will run OK once but then when I run it again I get "1062 - Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'".

How do I properly set up an auto-increment primary key?

Here is the table structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `CommentTable`;
CREATE TABLE `CommentTable` (
  `postID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `userID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`commentID`)
)
```

Comment: Table definitions are often useful at this point

Comment: May we see your table create statement?

Comment: @user9993 Edited the answer. You must be set `AUTO_INCREMENT` in field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to put the field `postID`

```
INSERT INTO CommentTable (userID, comment) VALUES ("test", "test")
```

Edit your table as:

```
CREATE TABLE `CommentTable` (
  `postID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `comment` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postID`)
)
```

Comment: Yeah, don't insert into the PK I the first place. Auto increments are not the same as defaults.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I had selected the tick box to make it autoincrement with the designer I was using but I'm guessing it didn't actually generate the SQL for it looking at what I posted. Your code works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had the same issue where Auto Increment was not saved. It failed every time I tried to save it. My problem was that I had a record where the value was 0 instead of 1, so I updated that record value to a non-zero value, then tried saving the Auto Increment, and it worked.

The zero(0) value in the Primary Index field was causing the ALTER tablename to fail. Once it worked, I put the value back to 0.